# Rooted Pixel 6 CPU DVFS control without userspace governor

Tags: root-access, cpu

So I recently rooted my Pixel 6 (Android 13) using Magisk and tried to control the CPU frequency, but it did not have `userspace` CPU governor. I tried to set `scaling_setspeed` in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ with no luck. Also tried setting `scaling_max_freq` and `scaling_min_freq` using the maximum frequency and `scaling_governor` as `performance` mode, but when workloads start, the frequency would drop. Is there a way to set and fix the frequency without installing userspace CPU governor?

It was to my understanding that `performance` mode would keep the CPU at max frequency, but even then, that was not the case.

Comment: Are you aware that your CPU has three different core types, each with an own max frequency (2x2.80 GHz Cortex-X1, 2x2.25 GHz Cortex-A76, 4x1.80 GHz Cortex-A55). Not sure how the cpu governor handles environments with different CPU cores.

Comment: Yeah, it's to my understanding that each core cluster can run it's own CPU governor. For example, I have the A55 clusters as performance, A76 as powersave, and X1 as sched_pixel